# Redirect all aspx in a subdirectory to new location

Tags: htaccess

How can I redirect:

```
http://example.com/subdir/a.aspx
http://example.com/subdir/b.aspx
http://example.com/subdir/c.aspx
...
```

to:

```
http://example.com/subdir/
```

with `.htaccess` please?

Note, I have these on my new site:

```
http://example.com/subdir/a/
http://example.com/subdir/b/
http://example.com/subdir/c/
http://example.com/subdir/1/
http://example.com/subdir/2/
http://example.com/subdir/3/
...
```

and they must not be affected.

Edit:

`/a.aspx` and `/a/` are just examples, and not related.

Comment: Presumably `/a.aspx` and `/a/` are not related? Do you currently have one or more `.htaccess` files? Do you have any existing directives in your `.htaccess` file(s)?

Comment: @MrWhite Edited above, and there is just one `.htaccess`, some existing rules like `Redirect /contact.aspx /offices/` plus some WP generated lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...some existing rules like `Redirect /contact.aspx /offices/` plus some WP generated lines.

Since this is a WordPress site, that is presumably already using mod_rewrite as part of the "front-controller" then you should avoid mixing in mod_alias (`Redirect` and `RedirectMatch`) redirect directives. Since the two modules run at different times during the request, despite their apparent order in the config file (mod_rewrite runs first) then you can get some unexpected conflicts. At the very least, it is inefficient, since the URL gets rewritten before the mod_alias `Redirect` occurs.

Any mod_alias `Redirect` directives should be converted to the "equivalent" mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` and placed *before* the existing WordPress directives. For example, in the case of the above "temporary" redirect from `/contact.aspx` to `/offices/`, this would be written as:

```
RewriteRule ^contact\.aspx$ /offices/ [R=302,L]
```

Note the absent slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

If this is intended to be permanent, then change the 302 (temporary) to 301 (permanent) but only once you have confirmed that all is working OK. (Note that the `Redirect` directive you posted in the comment is a temporary-302 redirect.)

Then, to redirect all requests for `.aspx` files in the `/subdir` directory to the subdirectory root, ie. `/subdir/`, then you would do the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(subdir/)[^/]+\.aspx$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

`(subdir/)` - This captures the name of the subdirectory (to save repetition) and is referenced with the `$1` backreference in the *substitution*.

`[^/]+` - This matches 1 or more non-`/` characters. So, any filename, but not a URl-path that contains multiple path segments. ie. It won't match `/subdir/foo/a.aspx`.

I should just add, that from an SEO standpoint, redirecting en masse to a common target like this is a bit dubious. It will likely to be seen as a soft-404 in the eyes of Google. And could be confusing for users, unless the target page is in someway related or contains relevant information for the user.

Comment: Works well. But I had to put it above the [WP rules](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/). Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, as I mentioned above, "...and placed _before_ the existing WordPress directives." If they are placed _after_ the WP rules and these `.aspx` files don't exist then the redirects would not even get processed, since the request would be routed through WordPress first (which is the purpose of the WP rules - the "front-controller").

Comment: Re "...this is a bit dubious..." I know that too. I don't have a better choice. Previously, it was `/subdir/doe-a-john.aspx`. New url becomes to `/subdir/john-a-doe/`, and some don't follow the exact reversed `last-m-first` name pattern. So that I just redirect them all to the index/listing page.